# How can I add a nested design-time property to a user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, properties

I have a user control that contains a number of panel controls.  The user control has logic to set the visibility of each panel, based on the values of some variables contained in the user control.

I would like to enhance this functionality by adding the following enumeration:

```
public enum Visibility
{
    Default,
    Always,
    Never
}
```

where `Default` would use the current logic to set the panel's visibility, but `Always` would (obviously) make the panel always visible, and `Never` would always hide the panel.

I would also like to add a "nested" design-time property named something like `PanelVisiblity` that the developer could expand, and see the panel names listed below, and allow them to assign a value from the `Visibility` enumeration for each.

If I add properties like this:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public Visibility ActivePanel { get; set; }
    public Visibility CodePanel { get; set; }
}
```

the `ActivePanel` and `CodePanel` properties appear in the Properties window in Visual Studio, and I can set them to one of the three values in the enum.  However, when I refactored my code to try to create a nested property like this:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public class PanelVisibility
    {
        public enum Visibility
        {
            Default,
            Always,
            Never
        }

        public Visibility ActivePanel { get; set; }
        public Visibility CodePanel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I do not get an expandable `PanelVisiblity` property, I get a disabled `Visiblity` property, where the value is the namespace of class, plus 'PanelVisibility'.

I have Googled a number of variations in phrasing this search, but have not been able to find anything like what I'm looking for.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for the same functionality as a DockPanel offers.

I'd suggest you that instead of re-inventing the wheel you should use one the available implementations to you such as :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx

http://dockpanel2012.codeplex.com/

https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite

Comment: I have looked at the links that you provided, but don't think that solves my issue.  First, I am using Visual Studio 2010 (added tag to my issue) so the codeplex example doesn't help.  Also, I would still like to know how to create a nested property.  I have other cases where I would like use them, other than the example described above.